# TYPO3 9.5: avoid throwing exeption on missing image

Tags: exception, migration, typo3

My TYPO3 9.5 installation throws the following exeption when an image is missing:

```
TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception
Folder "/uploads/tx_owlslider/tosoh.gif/" does not exist.
```

TYPO3 8.7 did not do that.

I also tried this in TYPO3_CONTEXT "Production".

How could I avoid this error, especially in production environment ?

Thanks !

Comment: Don't use missing files ;-) Does the file exist? If so, FAL seems not to know about it. Then start a File Index Update (eg via scheduler task). If the file does not exist, you should fix your content.

Comment: No, file is missing in fact. but I wonder why TYPO3 8.7 just didn't display the file but TYPO3 9.5 breaks the whole page with this error. Could I avoid this error or make a silent error, log entry f.eg. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the file object in a condition should do the trick.

```
<f:if condition="{item.itemimage}">
     <f:image class="lazyOwl" src="uploads/tx_owlslider/{item.itemimage}" height=. "{settings.slideHeight}" alt="{item.itemname}"/>
</f:if>
```

Comment: This seems proper and it's how I am helping me right now, but I find it ugly. Such a handler should be intelligent enough to deal with a missing image.

Comment: Especially when it comes to the src parameter, I agree with you. It's not trivial to implement a check that actually looks up if the file is existing, readable and a valid image file from within Fluid.

Comment: @j4k3 This doesn't work. See question, the {item.itemimage} property is not null, it's "tosoh.gif"

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed this in the Extension owl_slider itself.
If the image is physically missing, the f:image - tag should not be rendered:

```
 <v:media.exists file="uploads/tx_owlslider/{item.itemimage}">
      <f:then>
         <f:image class="lazyOwl" src="uploads/tx_owlslider/{item.itemimage}" height="{settings.slideHeight}" alt="{item.itemname}"/>
      </f:then>
      <f:else>
          {item.itemname}
      </f:else>
</v:media.exists>
```

Comment: Good idea. Should be marked as accepted answer.